# JBoss 5.1.0 disabled HDScanner, undeploying post restart doesn't work

Tags: jboss5.x

I have disabled the HDScanner bean (by removing `JBOSS_HOME/deploy/hdscanner-jboss-beans.xml`) in JBoss 5.1.0 so that I must do all deployments to running instances through Twiddle (applications found in the deployment directory are automatically deployed on startup).

After I have done this I can deploy and undeploy a war by using the following commands:

`twiddle.sh -s localhost invoke "jboss.system:service=MainDeployer" deploy "file:/path/to/my.war"`

`twiddle.sh -s localhost invoke "jboss.system:service=MainDeployer" undeploy "file:/path/to/my.war"`

This works fine.

However, if I restart JBoss between the deploy and the undeploy, when I try to undeploy the app using twiddle, the app remains deployed and the JBoss logs display :

> 2011-04-18 14:30:41,318 WARN  [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer] (WorkerThread#0[10.21.4.61:43700]) undeploy 'file:/path/to/my.war' : package not deployed

Am I doing something wrong, expecting something that's not possible, or is this a bug in JBoss?

If I am doing something wrong, what is the correct way to undeploy an app that has been deployed using twiddle on an instance of JBoss that has been subsequently restarted?

---

## Edit

Without looking at the source code of JBoss, it seems to me that apps that are deployed on startup are managed in a different place from those deployed through Twiddle. Ie if an app is deployed at startup it is not known of by the mechanism accessed through Twiddle, hence the "package not deployed" error.

So, is there a way to access this other deployment manager through Twiddle such that apps that are present at startup can still be undeployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a lot of testing on this, and basically apps that are found at startup are (rightly) considered to be part of the JBoss 'core' and are therefore deployed automatically as part of the startup process. This applies for things such as the jmx-console, and therefore applies for other `.war`s too. Whether through design or through consequence, these resources that have been automatically deployed during startup cannot be managed by `twiddle` invokations.